# How can I make the speakers on my 21.5" iMac work with Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, mac, speakers

I recently clean installed Ubuntu 18.04 (specifically, I have 18.04.3 LTS) on my iMac 21.5". I am unable to get audio to work through the internal speakers. Audio **does** work with headphones plugged into the jack. Bluetooth audio largely does not work (although I've had patchy sound come through it before). I'm wondering how to fix this. I've looked through several support pages, and I couldn't find anywhere that my problem was reproduced exactly. I did try a few things that were suggested anyway, with no success. I restarted my `pulseaudio` daemon, but that didn't help. I also added my user account to the `audio` group (which may have already been done), but that didn't change anything either.

In `Settings > Sound`, I've made sure "Speakers - Built-in Audio" is selected, and it is by default. Some people seemed to have issues with the HDMI audio option getting in the way, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me. I would be extremely grateful for any suggestions. I'm also curious about whether the Bluetooth audio issue is connected or separate.

**Edit:** In the `pavucontrol` window (screenshot below), the display bar (the gray bar below volume) shows sound being played. However, I am never able to hear anything.

[image]

Output of a couple requested commands:

```
$ pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xb1610000 irq 55"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "160c"
        device.product.name = "Broadwell-U Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "iMac"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb1614000 irq 52"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8ca0"
        device.product.name = "9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 800, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 860, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 700, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 760, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5560, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 48507 /  74%,   front-right: 48507 /  74%
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100%
    volume steps: 128
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "CS4208 Analog"
        alsa.id = "CS4208 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb1614000 irq 52"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8ca0"
        device.product.name = "9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Cirrus Logic CS4208"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10134208,106b8100,00100300"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same or very similar issue, but I've found that if I go to Configuration in pavucontrol there are 2 devices listed. I think the first is HDMI. The second one seems to be the internal speakers, but for some reason I can't fathom sound comes out of the stereo speakers ONLY if I set it to 2.1 or 4.0 surround.

Also had to make sure my PCM was turned up in alsamixer.

At that point I can hear left and right channels seemingly coming from the same speaker. Hard to tell for sure though. Right channel is bassy and clear, left channel is tinny and quiet. Sure beats having no sound though.

The system volume doesn't change the volume though.
For that to work I had to edit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common and add the following

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

just above this section:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

I know this post is old but hopefully this helps someone, since it took me 4 hours of googling to figure out.

[Here you can see my settings that work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pdLu.png)

Comment: omg years later this comment is worth its weight in gold!!!!! thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if sound from sound emitting applications is being routed to your speaker and volume is set correctly on pulseaudio volume control (pavucontrol). the "Playback" and "Output devices" menus should be relevant. This should also extend to your bluetooth device since you don't seem to be having issues connecting to it.

alsamixer is also an application you can look at to see if your speaker seems to be preforming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked `pavucontrol`, and when I play a YouTube video, the visualization bar seems to be responding as it should under Built-in Audio Analog Stereo (Port: Speakers). The volume is also set reasonably and not muted. However, no sound is being emitted. Do you have any ideas about what to do next?

Comment: @astropickle what about on the "Output devices" menu? does speakers output look normal? my assumption is that your device thinks headphones are plugged in so it ends up turning off the speakers. open up alsamixer in the terminal and check if your speaker is muted there.

Comment: This was in the Output Devices menu. Sorry for the confusion. Yes, the speakers output looks normal. The system seems to be able to tell when the headphones are plugged in vs. unplugged. Expanding the Port dropdown, it shows Headphones (unplugged) beneath Speakers (which is selected). I also looked at `alsamixer`, and it was a bit confusing, but things generally seem to be fine. Do you have any specific direction(s) you could give to check things in there?

Comment: Actually, I don't see anything resembling speakers in `alsamixer`. The bars shown are Master, Headphone, PCM, Mic Boost, S/PDIF, S/PDIF Default PCM, Auto-Mute Mode, and Internal Mic Boost. The two S/PDIF things have the `00` in a green box with no attached bar. I disabled Auto-Mute Mode, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @astropickle that is strange. there should be a Speaker option under alsamixer as well. when you unplug and replug headphones you should be able to see in alsamixer that heaphones get muted and speakers get unmuted and then vice versa.

Comment: can you report the results of 
`pacmd list-cards` and `pacmd list-sinks`?

Comment: Interesting. Yes, the headphones do get muted, but speakers do not appear in alsamixer. I'll edit my original post with that `pacmd` info shortly.

Comment: @astropickle I see. It is strange because your built-in audio card seems healthy and both your speaker port is recognized.

Comment: @astropickle I am not definitively sure what is causing this problem and why alsamixer doesn't recognize your speaker. I can't think of anything that would break speakers while keeping headphones intact beyond driver communication issue since they are on the same card on your machine and the thing that differentiates them is input to the driver. My hunch is driver issues for the sound card you have or it could also be malformed calls to your sound card driver.

Comment: @astropickle have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu or less extremely reinstalling alsa and sound related packages? I believe `linux-sound-base` and `alsa-base` are the main packages.